# Ruby ActiveSupport array split vs string split

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, split, activesupport

```
"abc def ".split(" ")
```

returns

```
["abc", "def"]
```

Thus, I was expecting:

```
["a", "b", "c", " ", "d", "e", "f", " "].split(" ")
```

to return

```
[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]
```

but it returned

```
[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], []]
```

I read through the source code doing the split in active_support/core_ext/array/grouping.rb (I am using ActiveSupport 4.0.0 with ruby 2.0.0-p247). You can find the 2 lines of doc here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-split and the code is the following:

```
def split(value = nil, &block)
    inject([[]]) do |results, element|
      if block && block.call(element) || value == element
        results << []
      else
        results.last << element
      end

      results
    end
  end
```

That explains how it does the split.

Now, is that the intended behavior or is that an ActiveSupport bug?

Comment: Software will run exactly as it is coded, but may not run as it is intended. You would never be able to tell if a certain behavior is a bug or a specification by looking at the code, but maybe able to tell by reading the specifications.

Comment: I added a link to the doc. The examples there do not cover this edge case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably intended behavior rather than a bug. According to the documentation, splitting an array:

> Divides the array into one or more subarrays based on a delimiting
>   value or the result of an optional block.

This makes no guarantees about contiguous or leading spaces.

On the other hand, the [Ruby core documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-split) for `String#split` states:

> If pattern is a String, then its contents are used as the delimiter
>   when splitting str. If pattern is a single space, str is split on
>   whitespace, with leading whitespace and runs of contiguous whitespace
>   characters ignored.

As you can see, the behavior you expect only works with whitespace, not for just any string.

```
 "abc ccc def ".split("c")
 => ["ab", " ", "", "", " def "]
```

When splitting an array, the concept of "whitespace" doesn't really make sense any more. So I think the behavior is sensible, if perhaps counterintuitive at first.